# Meteor dynamic templates from http call and form

Tags: java, forms, templates, meteor, dynamic

I'm currently recovering JSON formated from HTTP CALL.
This function is launched with parameters provided by a form template and parameters are pushed on variables with submit event.

My function **getusershttp** is able to return some results that I'm able to see with **console.log(results.content);**:

```
"results" : [
      {
         "name" : {
            "first" : "Billy",
            "last" : "McKornic"
         },
         "id" : "a1c3fd06c71ccc50998baa02074976b4d639e4cf",
         "situation" : "free",
      },
      {
         "name" : {
            "first" : "Dough",
            "last" : "Wallas"
         },
         "id" : "5694c02beaf20d2d4b5747668b82264af8547e33",
         "situation" : "occuped",
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I would like to put each result in my articles template with:

```
<template name="articles">
    {{#each results}}
        <header>
            <p>{{name.first}} {{name.last}}</p>
            <p>{{id}}</p>
            <p>{{situation}}</p>
        </header>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

What template event and function I must create in order to provide each results data?
Currently I have:

```
Template.articles.helpers({
    results : function() {
      return Meteor.call("getusershttp",FormParamX,FormParamY);   
    }
  });
```

But I have a java error on page loading since my form is not submited and FormParamX and FormParamY are not populated.
How do I force my Template (event & function) to wait my form submited in order to start providing results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Stephen tips I took a look with session variables and it works!

In order to help, I provide the solution according my exemple.

First, my form template event function:

```
Template.search.events({
  'submit form':function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var FormParamX = event.target.FormParamX.value;
    var FormParamY = event.target.FormParamY.value;

    Meteor.call("getusershttp",FormParamX,FormParamY,function(error, results) {
      Session.set("MyUsers",results.content);
    });
  }
});
```

Here, my session variable **MyUsers** store my HTTP CALL JSON output.

Then, my articles template helpers:

```
Template.articles.helpers({
  results : function() {
    if (Session.get("MyUsers")) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(Session.get("MyUsers")).results);
      return JSON.parse(Session.get("MyUsers")).results;
    };
  }
});
```

Helpers only provide session variable MySearch value if it have some values.
I tested changing my form and on each submit, helpers provide different values as expected.

My template articles is not able now to provide each results but this is another issue.

*Update: In order to provide each results value, I need to parse my JSON output. I updated the code and now my template is working.*

Another time, thanks Stephen!

Answer (score 1):

Set the values for FormParamX and Y to [reactive variables](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var), then you can simply do:

```
results() {
    if( Template.instance().FormParamX.get() && Template.instance().FormParamY.get() ) {
        return Meteor.call("getusershttp",FormParamX,FormParamY);   
    }
}
```

Then any time the form parameters change, you'll recall your Meteor method and get the appropriate data.

Additional documentation on reactive variables are [here](https://docs.meteor.com/#reactivevar_pkg), and there is also a nice [walkthrough](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables/) on TheMeteorChef.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Do you think I can use only session variable instead of reactive variable? If I understand well, FormParamX/Y get values from my Form Template. I have to define these variables with session variables and add your test on my articles template in order to be sure these variables are populated before returning my call.